# How to rename a partition in OS X?

Tags: macos, partitioning

I'm able to *erase* a partition using the Disk Utility, but I want to change the name without losing data. How is it possible?

Comment: If the partition is mounted, you can rename it just like any other file or folder by highlighting and pressing enter

Answer (score 93, accepted):

To rename the volume, enter the following in Terminal:

```
/usr/sbin/diskutil rename oldname newname
```

for example:

```
/usr/sbin/diskutil rename "Macintosh HD" "Mac Disk"
```

---

You can also right-click a partition in Finder (in *Computername* at the top level of the hierarchy), select *Get Info*, and enter the new name there.

Comment: If you rename the volume where your home directory is, don't forget to update your home directory path in the System Preferences before rebooting.

Comment: @ChristianLescuyer That's only a problem if your home directory isn't on the root volume (i.e. the default), and isn't assigned a static mount point e.g. through `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: It worked for me by specifying the path to the mounted volume:

`diskutil rename /Volumes/UNTITLED\ 1/ newname`

Comment: I'm on 10.9.5 and I get the error ``Failed to rename volume: Invalid request (-69886)``

Comment: 10.11.x - this worked for me. Thanks +1

Answer (score 19):

Or just go to Finder and change the name in the left hand column, just like a file.

Comment: Too simple.  ;)  You get my vote.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where finder was repeatedly restarting which made the mac unusable. Went into single-user mode and spotted that the volume had a lengthy name of strange characters. Could not rename it - since GUI was unavailable and the rename command in single-user needs you to type the name (without being able to cut/paste). This in in High Sierra on a 2015 mac mini. Turns out if you boot into recovery mode with CMD-R, go into disk utility, highlight the disk with the bad volume name then click the name beside the picture of the disk (or do File Rename) it lets you change it. This fixed all my problems and the machine seems fine now.